# what's the meaning of non-abstract empty method in an abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm reading some source code and can't figure out why there are two non-abstract empty method in an abstract class.

The abstract class was like:

```
public abstract class AbstractMode extends TimerTask{

    abstract public void initial();

    abstract public int getAllConsumption();

    public void checkTemperature(int currentTem) {};

    public void checkConsumption() {};

    abstract public long updateHistory();

    abstract public void updateMYSQLCurrentDevice(int counter);
}
```

Only one of it's concrete class override and use them, but I can directly implement these method in the concrete class right? So I was wondering if them could be taken off, what's the use of them?

Comment: If you want to provide any default implementation, you can provide it here, so that multiple concrete classes won't have duplicate code.

Comment: honestly, in my eyes there is non (if they are empty)

Comment: Non-abstract methods in abstract classes generally appear by factorizing code of concrete classes. I doubt this was obtained from such.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Yeah I get your point, but since only one concrete classes use and override it, they seems useless to me.

Comment: @SkyWalker Thank you! How can I just not found it before

Comment: In this particular case, I don't see why it has been done. Unless its the authors way of trying to say 'you need not implement this method, it's optional', but still it smells bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this is a code smell. Here's why:

1. If these methods were intended to do nothing, why do they exist ?
2. If they were intended to define a behaviour, they would have an implementation (other than empty) and would be made `final` to express that intent.
3. If they were intended to be overriden, the intent clearly fails to be
   expressed because noone will have a clue that these methods must be
   overriden and should therefore be made `abstract`.

To get rid of this smell, I would either delete them or make them `abstract`.

Comment: an abstract class can have abstract method or non abstract method also

Comment: @DhavalJoshi Indeed, it can. But I consider an **abstract** class having **non-abstract** method a **code smell**.

Comment: yes thats why voted up bro

Answer (score 2):

While not the most common case, sometimes it is handy in the context of a template method. In this case there is a method that defines the flow, leaving the concrete implementation of some parts to its subclasses. In some cases a default concrete behavior is to do nothing,

> leaving the concrete method in the base class empty, but allowing
>   customization in the subclass by overriding it

.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite useful for cases where overriding something is optional. For example, in `java.awt.event`, there is an interface:

```
public interface MouseListener extends EventListener {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e);
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e);
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e);
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e);
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e);
}
```

and then there is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseWheelListener, MouseMotionListener {
```

that has plenty of empty implementations. So, instead of implementing the interface, you can extend the adapter and only override the methods you're actually interested in, without adding empty implementations for all the methods you don't even care about.

This makes for much nicer and more compact implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what it is, if the empty methods had some code. These methods are considered implemented. Since only one concrete class implements this abstract class, the empty methods make no sense.

Comment: ya sometimes does not make any sense but can be useful for customization